# Incompatible element type Id for collection

Tags: apex

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I created a list, I loop through the list with a query and then I add the query id. When I compile I get:

> Incompatible element type Id for collection

I tried changing the list to a set, to a map, tried addall(), put(). Nothing is letting me save.

```
    public void deleteSchedule(Set<Id> revPipeline)
{
    List<Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c> scheduleToDelete = new List<Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c>();
    for(Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c revPipeSchedule : [SELECT Id,
                                                               Revenue_Pipeline__r.Id
                                                         FROM Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c
                                                         WHERE Revenue_Pipeline__r.Id In :revPipeline])
    {
        scheduleToDelete.add(revPipeSchedule.Id);
    }
    try{
        delete scheduleToDelete;        
    }   
    catch (DmlException e){
        // womp womp
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a `List<Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c>`, you should add individual `Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c` elements.

```
scheduleToDelete.add(revPipelineSchedule);
```

Although you don't need to iterate the list at all, frankly. Depending on how you want to handle the `DmlException`, you don't necessarily even need to cache it.

```
try
{
    delete [/*query*/];
}
catch (DmlException d)
{
    // DON'T LEAVE THIS BLOCK EMPTY
}
```

Although often, you want to iterate back through the list in the failure case, in which case you can simply assign it directly from the query.

```
List<MyObject__c> records = [/*query*/];
try
{
    delete records;
}
catch (DmlException d)
{
    // do something
}
```